# C# Office 365 Sharepoint File Download - ServerObjectNullReferenceException

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm trying to get a list of file URLs from a SharePoint list but keep running into a ServerObjectNullReferenceException every time I try to access a property from the File.

Can't seem to find a way to load this Server Object from the ClientContext or through the ListItemCollection itself.

What am I missing?

```
            SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in "password".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);

            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("url");
            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("username", passWord);

            var list = clientContext.Web.GetList("/Files/Apps/");

            var listItems = list.GetItems(new CamlQuery());

            clientContext.Load(listItems,
                items => items.Include(
                item => item.File));

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            // Any time I access item.File I get the ServerObjectNullReferenceException
            foreach (var item in listItems)
            {
                string test = String.Format("{0}", item.File.ServerRelativeUrl);
            }
```